# Nested Forms with more than 2 child in angular2

Tags: angular2-forms

I am maybe a week with this problem, I have a code that use menu and submenu.

I have a menu that has name and submenu, and submenu that contain name.

My menu.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormArray, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Http, Headers, Response, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router'
declare var $: any;
import { Menu_Service } from '../menu.service';
import { MenuInterface } from '../menu.interface';
import { PagetitleService } from '../../../core/pagetitle/pagetitle.service';
var swal = require('sweetalert');
@Component({
    //   moduleId:module.id,
    selector: 'app-menu',
    templateUrl: './menu.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./menu.component.scss'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {

    public data = {};
    public myForm: FormGroup;
    public route: ActivatedRoute;
    public router: Router;
    public http: Http;
    public headers: Headers;
    public mensagem: string = '';
    public service: Menu_Service;

    constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder, pt: PagetitleService, route: ActivatedRoute, router: Router, http: Http, service: Menu_Service) {

        pt.setTitle('');
        this.service = service;
        this.route = route;
        this.router = router


        this._load();
    }

    private _load() {

    }


    ErrorMessage(error) {
        swal('Oops...', error, 'error');
    }

    //I create here my form group here

    ngOnInit() {
        this.myForm = this._fb.group({
            role: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]],
            menus: this._fb.array([this.initMenu()]),
        });



        this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
            let id = params['id'];
            if (id) {
                this.service
                    .searchId(id)
                    .subscribe(data => {
                        this.data = data.data[0]
                        const subcontrol = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls['submenus'];
                        const control = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls['menus'];
                        for (var i in this.data.menus) {
                            const nameCtrl = this.loadMenu(this.data.menus[i].name);
                            control.push(nameCtrl);

                        }

                    }, erro => console.log(erro))
            }
            else{
                this.addMenu(); 
            };
        });


        // add address

    }
    initMenu() {
        return this._fb.group({
            name: ['', Validators.required],
            submenu: this._fb.array([this.initSubMenu()]),
        });
    }

    initSubMenu() {
        return this._fb.group({
            name: ['', Validators.required]
        });
    }

    loadMenu(value: String) {
        return this._fb.group({
            name: [value, Validators.required]
        });
    }


    loadSubMenu(value: String) {
        return this._fb.group({
            name: [value, Validators.required]
        });
    }


    addMenu() {
        const control = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls['menus'];
        const menuCtrl = this.initMenu();
        control.push(menuCtrl);

        /* subscribe to individual address value changes */
        // addrCtrl.valueChanges.subscribe(x => {
        //   console.log(x);
        // })
    }

    removeMenu(i: number) {
        const control = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls['menus'];
        control.removeAt(i);
    }

    removeSubMenu(i: number) {
        const control = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls['submenus'];
        control.removeAt(i);
    }

    save(event:MenuInterface) {
        //   event.preventDefault();
        this.data.role = event.value.role;
        this.data.menus=event.value.menus;
        //  this.data.submenus=event.values.submenus;
        this.service
            .cadastra(this.data)
            .subscribe(res => {

                if (res.success) {

                    swal({
                        title: 'Good job!',
                        text: 'You clicked the button!',
                        type: 'success'
                    }, ()=>{
                        this.router.navigate(['/admin/menus/list'])
                    });

                }
                else {
                    this.ErrorMessage("Server off-line")
                }
            }, erro => console.log(erro));
    }
}
```

My menu.component.html

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <form [formGroup]="myForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="save(myForm)">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <label class="mt">Role</label>
                <input type="text" formControlName="role" [(ngModel)]="data.role" class="form-control">
                <small *ngIf="!myForm.controls.role.valid" class="text-danger help-block">Role is required (minimum 5 characters).</small>
            </div>

            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Menus for this Role: </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <!--
                        <div *ngFor="let menu of myForm.controls.menus.controls; let i=index">
                            <div class="row" formArrayName="menus">
                                <div class="col-md-12" [formGroupName]="i">
                                    Tste: {{myForm.controls.menus.controls.length}}
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your menu title here{{i}}" class="form-control" formControlName="name" />
                                    <small class="text-danger" [hidden]="myForm.controls.menus.controls[i].controls.name.valid">* name is required </small>
                                    <small type="button" style="cursor: default" *ngIf="myForm.controls.menus.controls.length > 1" (click)="removeMenu(i)" class="text-danger pull-right"><span class="ion-trash-a"></span> delete</small>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        -->

                        <div formArrayName="menus">
                            <div *ngFor="let menus of myForm.controls.menus.controls; let i=index">
                                <!-- address header, show remove button when more than one address available -->
                                <div>
                                    <span>menus {{i + 1}}</span>
                                    <span *ngIf="myForm.controls.menus.controls.length > 1"
                                          (click)="removeMenus(i)">
                                    </span>
                                </div>

                                <!-- Angular assigns array index as group name by default 0, 1, 2, ... -->
                                <div [formGroupName]="i">
                                    <!--street-->
                                    <div>
                                        <label>Name</label>
                                        <input type="text" formControlName="name">
                                        <!--display error message if street is not valid-->
                                        <small [hidden]="myForm.controls.menus.controls[i].controls.name.valid">
                                            Name is required
                                        </small>
                                    </div>
                                    <!--postcode-->
                                    <div>
                                        <label>SubMenu</label>
                                        <div *ngFor="let submenus of myForm.controls.menus.controls[i].controls.submenus; let ii=index">
                                            <div [formGroupName]="ii">
                                                <input type="text" formControlName="name">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">

                                <div class="col-md-12 text-left">
                                    <a (click)="addMenu()" style="cursor: default"><span class="ion-ios-plus"></span> Add another menu</a>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body text-center">

                        <button type="submit" [disabled]="!myForm.valid" class="btn  btn-primary ripple">Save</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain what is happening, and how it differs from the expected result?

Comment: Its come duplicate, because has :



                name: ['', Validators.required],
                submenu: this._fb.array([this.initSubMenu()]),


so the result is two names.